# Button size shrinks after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

The HTML is as below:

```
<input type="button" class="button" id="addBtnId" value="Save" />
<input type="reset" class="button" id="resetBtnId" value="Reset" />
```

Before an AJAX Call my buttons look like this:

[image: buttons]

And after AJAX Call my buttons shrinks and be like this:

[image: shrinked buttons]

**AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: saveCityUrl,
        data :  $("#cityForm").serializeObject() ,
        success: function(response){
            var cityform = $(response).find('#cityDivId').html(); 
            $('#cityDivId').html( cityform );
        }           
    });
```

Comment: Seems like some classes are get removed after ajax call. check the code before and after the ajax call.

Comment: How would one make out without seeing actual code ? Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: same code. just the form is being reloaded.

Comment: `AJAX` and `form-submit`..Both are different things..Generally people expect only one thing to happen...

Comment: Open your browser console, focus to the button element and what happen after ajax call. Maximum suggestion without seeing any code.

Comment: AJAX Code added to the original post.

Comment: and what is 'response' returned value ?

Comment: And what is '#cityDivId' ? parent element wrapping those button ?

Comment: A HTML page. Div: cityDivId is a part of it. This part reloads. Buttons are inside this div.

Comment: Please add complete div including #cityDivId element, thats response value and code used to populated the response. This way we can help.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that you have CSS styling on the padding in the buttons, and then when the Ajax call occurs you are replacing the div contents with new content, but because it was not in the DOM at the page load, even through they have the same id's as the buttons they are replacing they are not being affected by the style rules.

If this is the case and you are replacing DOM contents, you may need to consider inline styling the new content.

Comment: Thank, adding inline styling helps a but. but how can I keep the button look OK without adding inline? My ajax code is added to the original post

Comment: one thought - have the buttons outside the form and dont replace them, but use the onclick event from the to trigger he form submission and reset functions.

Comment: Keep the css styling for the buttons separately and mark every property as !important.